# When citing inside caption, it starts at number one

Tags: floats

When using \cite inside a figures caption, it ignores all my previous citation and assign the used source as number one? I have even tried with \protect, but still it starts at 1.

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=60mm,width=145mm]{a picture.png}
\protect\caption{some text (figure from \protect\cite{Sommerville2009Software}) }
\label{agile_vs_planned_design}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is, you have a list of figures, where your citation is also displayed. This is the first occurrence of a citation and therefore, it is the number one.

There are two things you can do:

1. use the optional argument for the caption: `\caption[caption without citation for lof]{caption with citation}`
2. you can use the `notoccite` package.